# Не упускайте возможность или возможности?

Tags: управление, родительный-или-винительный

Как правильно: не упускайте возможность, возможности, возможностей.., например, помочь нуждающимся?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **не упускайте возможности помочь нуждающимся.**

**Комментарий**

1) **Множественное число не подойдет**, здесь именно возможность (обобщенное понятие), а возможности ― это конкретные средства для решения какой-либо задачи.

2) **Родительный падеж** ― основной падеж при отрицании, книжный и нейтральный вариант. Чем более отвлеченное понятие, тем более востребован этот падеж.

3) **Винительный падеж** ― ослабленное отрицание, больше подходит для конкретных предметов и разговорной речи.

4) Интересно обратить внимание на частотность употребления выражений у**пускать/упустить**.  **Упустить** ― здесь речь идет о конкретном случае, и В.п. используется чаще.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

**(1) Не упускайте возможности (3 примера)**

Не упускайте возможности вовремя обучить ребёнка элементарным нормам вежливости. Не упускайте возможности прогуляться по улочкам города, вдоль берега реки, в парке.

**(2) Не упускайте возможность (0 примеров)**

**(3) Не упустите возможности  (2 примера)**

Если судьбе когда-нибудь угодно будет привести вас в окрестности Флоренции, не упустите возможности побывать в парке «Виллы камелий».

**(4) Не упустите возможность (5 примеров)**

Не упустите возможность сделать отличный подарок себе и любимым людям. Не упустите возможность побродить по его улицам, встретиться с другими людьми, чем-то очень похожими на нас

Comment: В книгах таких примеров гораздо больше находится: соотношение похожее, но нет "нулевых" результатов для несовершенной формы глагола, в варианте же с глаголом "упустить" (конкретность) винительный падеж "побеждает" с явным перевесом.

Comment: Но всё-таки тенденция   в общих чертах совпадает.

Answer (score 1):

Первое - если возможность есть или появилась, второе - о гипотетической возможности (напр. если/когда она у вас будет), третье - когда есть *несколько* конкретных возможностей или их *много*, а воспользоваться предлагается одной из них.

Answer (score 1):

Справочник Розенталя "Управление в русском языке" говорит, что в этом случае употребляется, как правило, родительный падеж.

> Падеж управляемого слова при переходном глаголе с отрицанием —
>   родительный или  винительный. 
>   1. Родительный падеж, как правило, употребляется:  
> ...
>
> 5) при выражении дополнения отвлеченным существительным: не теряет
>   времени; не обнаруживает желания; не скрывает радости; не делает
>   уступок; не дает оснований; не осуществляет контроля; не упускает
>   случая;

Но в разговорной речи допускается факультативное употребление:

> 3. Факультативное употребление форм родительного и  винительного падежей при переходном глаголе с отрицанием  обычно связано со
>      стилистическим различием; конструкции с  родительным падежом
>      характерны для книжной речи; конструкции с винительным падежом — для
>      речи разговорной. *Так и умрешь, не выговорив это слово (М.Г.).*

Выбор множественного числа сомнителен, но зависит от контекста, конечно.

Comment: У Розенталя нет утверждения о тенденции ("как правило") к родительному падежу дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием, он лишь различает три разных случая:  "в одних случаях [8 подпунктов] явно преобладает употребление родительного падежа дополнения, в других [13 подпунктов] – употребление винительного падежа, в третьих [1 пункт] – наблюдается факультативное их использование." http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04

Comment: @Alex_ander Я сказал, что рассматриваемый случай относится к тем, в которых, как правило, употребляется Р.П. И даже подтвердил это точной цитатой. Я ничего не говорю об общих тенденциях — где Вы это увидели?

Comment: Да, сейчас вижу "в этом случае". Но у нас случай без контекста.

Comment: @Alex_ander Ну так про факультативное употребление я тоже сказал, и про контекст. Дочитайте ответ до конца, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я думаю, что здесь вариативность возможна не только по стилистическим причинам (разговорный или книжный стиль), а и ( в большей степени) по причинам конкретности ("у вас сегодня есть возможность, и это редкий случай помочь..." и т. д.) или абстрактности "случая". И об этом есть в первом подпункте раздела о винительном падеже (из моей ссылки).

Comment: Да, такое возможно, я думаю. Но всё же Розенталь (в моей ссылке) в п.3. для Р.П. приводит "не упускает случая" без контекста, а в п.7 "не упускает возможности" вообще как устойчивое выражение (по Вашей ссылке это тоже есть). Поэтому я считаю правильным при отсутствии контекста рекомендовать именно этот вариант.

Comment: "Не упускает случая" (подшутить и др.) больше в идиоматическом смысле употребляется. Важен _вид_ (соверш./несоверш.) глагола, очень заметны различия (обратное статистическое соотношение по предпочтению падежей) для сочетаний с **не упустите / не упускайте** (в первом случае винительный падеж в книжках доминирует).

Comment: @Alex_ander Не хочу спорить хотя бы потому, что во многом согласен с Вами. Но пусть будет и формальный ответ и это обсуждение в комментариях. (Проще всего было бы требовать от автора вопроса дать контекст, но ведь её, наверное, интересует как раз общая картина.)